# backward martingale convergence

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm trying to understand when a backward martingale is convergent.
I've obtained that if the backward martingale is convergent a.e., then it is convergent in $L^1$ to $E[M_1| F_{ \infty } ]$.

I'm having some trouble finding a result about convergence a.e., in other words i've not found some hypothesis that lead to convergence a.e.

I add the definition of backward martingale in order to explain my notation:

Let $(M_n) _{n \geq 1}$ a integrable process and $(F_n)_{n \geq 1}$ a family of $\sigma $-field non-increasing.
$M_n$ is a backward martingale if $M_n$ is $F_n$-measurable and $E[M_n|F_{n+1}]=M_{n+1}$.

$F_{\infty}$ denotes $\bigcap _{n \geq 1} F_n$.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Any discrete-time, backward martingale automatically converges a.e. and in $\mathrm L^1$.

Comment: I imagined that, i'm not able to prove that every backward martingale converges a.e

Comment: Do you know that $E(X|\mathcal F_n)$ converges a.s. and in $L^{1}$ for any $X$ with finite mean and any increasing sequence of $\sigma$ fields $\mathcal F_n$?

Comment: Standard proof uses Doob's upcrossing lemma. See e.g., [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec11Add.pdf), Theorem 5 page 7.